# When will widgets update after widget visibility change in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change visibility of two widgets one by one. In my case, i need to do some process then sleep 1s and change visibility of WidgetA. And sleep 1s chnage visibility of WidgetB. This is my code.

```
...// do process D
 Sleep(1000);
 WidgetA->setVisible(true);         
 Sleep(1000);
 WidgetB->setVisible(true);
```

But result is not what I want. The WidgetA and WidgetB 's visibility have been changed in same time after more than 2s after the process D finished.

1. Why WidgetA and WidgetB's visibility have been changed in same time? Don't they change in realtime when `WidgetA->setVisible(true);` have been executed? When will widgets update?
2. Why more than 2s ?

Comment: Why don't use QTimer?

Comment: Thank you, i  used QCoreApplication::processEvents(); and it work! But i just want to know when will widgets update in Qt? Do they update after one slot event finished? Or just wait in an event loop, updating after all the event finished not just one event

Comment: I hope you will find answer here                                           http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

Comment: When you setVisible(true), you only push showEvent to qt eventloop. It won't be dispatched right after calling function. Calling processEvents will force to dispatch all pending events in the eventloop.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. If now the event queues have 5 events in it. I   setVisible(true) and push showEvent into the queue. At that time, the GUI update will need be waited until 5 events finfished?

Comment: No. He will be immediately visible.

Comment: Looks like it's time to learn how GUIs work and what an event loop is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::Initialize()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    WidgetA->installEventFilter( this );
    WidgetA->setVisible( true );
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter( QObject *object, QEvent *event )
{
    if( object == WidgetA )
    {
        if( event->type() == QEvent::Show )
        {
            Sleep(1000);
            WidgetB->setVisible( true );
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter( object, event );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a timer to create a delay between setting WidgetA and WidgetB visible.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. If now the event queues have 5 events in it. I setVisible(true) and push showEvent into the queue. At that time, the GUI update will need be waited until 5 events finfished?